# MySQL ERROR 2006 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, terminal

I always after big query (bigger than in one line) get this `ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away`, but after that string it trying recconect and query completed succesfull.
I read other topics about same error, and there advised edic mysql conf file, and set `max_allowed_packet=64M` and `wait_timeout = 6000` but it did not help in my case.

Here is a screenshot of requests
 [image]
And other query.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, its on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration option for interactive connection is not **wait_timeout** but **interactive_timeout** try setting this variable in your my.cnf
Also you can know current session timeout by querying

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%_timeout';
```

Comment: Yea, it is ! 
And now query performed more faster. I changed `interactive_timeout=30` to `interactive_timeout=3000`. 
Thanks !